# Replace whole words from blacklist array instead of partial matches

Tags: php, arrays, regex, filter, cpu-word

I have an array of words

```
$banned_names = array('about','access','account');
```

The actual array is very long a contains bad words so at risk of breaking any rule I just added an example, the issue I'm having is the following:

```
$title = str_ireplace($filterWords, '****', $dn1['title']);
```

This works however, one of my filtered words is 'rum' and if I was to post the word 'forum' it will display as 'fo****'

So I need to only replace the word with `****` if it matches the exact word from the array, if I was to give an example the phrase "Lets check the forum and see if anyone has rum", would be "Lets check the forum and see if anyone has ****".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the other answers but this uses `\b` in regex to match word boundaries (whole words). It also creates the regex-compatible banned list on the fly before passing to `preg_replace_callback()`.

```
$dn1['title'] = 'access forum'; 

$banned_names = array('about','access','account','rum');
$banned_list = array_map(function($r) { return '/\b' . preg_quote($r, '/') . '\b/'; }, $banned_names); 

$title = preg_replace_callback($banned_list, function($m) { 
   return $m[0][0].str_repeat('*', strlen($m[0])-1);
}, $dn1['title']);

echo $title; //a***** forum
```

Comment: Thanks, i like you code however some of my banned names contain special characters which i think is breaking the code, is there a way to modify this to prevent symbols (including spaces, periods, underscores and dashes) from breaking it?

Comment: Actually think it was my own mistake, one of my word contains a forward slash that was breaking the code. thank you

Comment: @Mystic You can add `preg_quote()` to the `array_map` line if your words have special characters: `return '/\b' . preg_quote($r, '/') . '\b/';`. I've edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That is very useful, thank you for the edit, since you certainly know your stuff here, i dont suppose you could save me hours of trying on how i can keep the first letter of the banned word, so using the same example as you made $title would result in a***** forum.

Comment: @Mystic Sure thing, just change the `return str_repeat('*', strlen($m[0]));` line with `return $m[0][0].str_repeat('*', strlen($m[0])-1);`. I updated the answer with the change.

Comment: My answer shows my lack of knowledge re: regex. Thanks for adding. Also like that you opted to replace per character instead of using the default 4 as provided in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex with `\W` to match a "non-word" character:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/\Wrum\W/i', 'the forum thing')); // returns 0 i.e. doesn't match
var_dump(preg_match('/\Wrum\W/i', 'the rum thing'));   // returns 1 i.e. matches
```

The `preg_replace()` method takes an array of filters like `str_replace()` does, but you'll have to adjust the list to include the pattern delimiters and the `\W` on both sides. You could store the full patterns statically in your list:

```
$banlist = ['/\Wabout\W/i','/\Waccess\W/i', ... ];
preg_replace($banlist, '****', $text);
```

Or adjust the array on the fly to add those bits.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use word boundaries (`\b`) instead of wrapping in `\W` as demonstrated in cOle2's answer because it not accommodate instances where the blacklisted word is at the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to look for your needles with a beginning/end of string tag after converting each string in your haystack to an array of strings, so you'll be matching on full words. Alternatively you can add spaces and continue to use str_ireplace() but that option would fail if your word is the first or last word in the string being checked.

Adding spaces (will miss first/last word, not reccomended):

You'll have to modify your filtering array first of course. And yes the foreach could be simpler, but I hope this makes clear what I'm doing/why.

```
foreach($filterWords as $key => $value){
    $filterWords[$key] = " ".$value." ";
}
str_ireplace ( $filterWords, "****", $dn1['title'] );
```

OR
Breaking up long string (recommended):

```
foreach($filterWords as $key => $value){
    $filterWords[$key] = "/^".$value."$/i"; //add regex for beginning/end of string value
}
preg_replace ( $filterWords, "****", explode(" ", $dn1['title']) );
```